# Can a field be disabled in View.py of Django project?

Tags: python, django

```
def resume_edit(request, r_id):

    r = Resume.get.object(pk=r_id)
    resume = ResumeModelForm(instance=r)

    resume.fields['email'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True 

    return render(request, 'resumes/resume.html', context)
```

I tried to do this but its not working, i know how to do it in Forms.py , but i want to know in views its possible or not?

Im using Django 2.0

Comment: What django version do you use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sir 2.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, since [django-1.9](/questions/tagged/django-1.9), a field has a [**`.disabled`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) attribute that can be set to `True`:

So we can use:

```
def resume_edit(request, r_id):
    r = Resume.get.object(pk=r_id)
    resume = ResumeModelForm(instance=r)

    resume.fields['email'].disabled = True 

    return render(request, 'resumes/resume.html', context)
```

This will not only ensure that the HTML of the corresponding form parts is disabled, but will also ignore possible changes when you *post* the `Form` (note that you of course first need to *disable* the field).

Since the `render(..)` call produces the HTML, the field should of course be altered *before* it is rendered, validated, or `.save()`'d.

The `.disabled` attribute is typically better than using `readonly`, etc. Since some form elements have a special way to disable the element at the HTML level (some use `disabled` instead). Furthermore like said before it does not only disable the form element at the HTML level. If a user wants to post malicuous values, then the form will simply ignore these.

Comment: and make sure you do this before sending your form to template

Comment: @WillemVanOnsen Thank you sir, its been  2 hours i was struggling to fix this.. thank you

Comment: shouldn't this be resume.fields['email'].field.disabled = True ? AFAICT setting the attribute on the "bound field" doesn't do much